# Overlapping of one string into another string highlighting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have a string which can be like

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged
```

Now, In this I have an json which has the string start and end offset which I want to highlight. Now, logic I am using is like this --

```
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, startoffset, endoffset) {
  var className = 'mark';
  console.log(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset));
  return content.replace(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset), '<span class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
}
//Only if you don't know if they are in the correct order:
jsonDataArray = jsonDataArray.sort((a, b) => a.startOffset - b.startOffset);

for (var i = jsonDataArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const item = jsonDataArray[i];
  responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset, item.endOffset, item.color);
};
$rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");
```

So, Here I am trying to highlight from the last value of the array so that the offset will not be changed. Now, In this there is one problem and that is like the overlapping .Now,Lets say ,

In this text I have highlighted `Lorem Ipsum has been` by adding  some span class . Now, for the next interation, if the startoffset and endoffset has a string which is nothing but `Ipsum has been the industry's standard` . Now, Here there will be overlapping of these two and then the highlighting is overlapping . So, I am not able get the exact text, because of that the offsets gets changed.

Now, Another solution which I applied was like -

```
var length = '<span class="mark"></span>'.length:
jsonDataArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
    responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset + (index * length), item.endOffset + (index * length), item.color);
});
$rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");
```

But here also the same problem, like if some part of one thing is present in another then it creates some problems. Can any one please help me with this ?

Comment: Check this [md-highlight-text.](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdHighlightText)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having keeping track of your indexes moving, I suggest you store the output string separately or in an array like I did below:

```js
const str = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged';

const highlights = [{startOffset: 2, endOffset: 16}, {startOffset: 68, endOffset: 75}, {startOffset: 80, endOffset: 92}];

const result = [];
let currentIndex = 0;

highlights.forEach(h => {
  result.push(str.substring(currentIndex, h.startOffset));
  result.push(`<span class="mark">${str.substring(h.startOffset, h.endOffset)}</span>`);
  currentIndex = h.endOffset;
});

result.push(str.substring(currentIndex, str.length));

document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = result.join('');
```

```css
.mark {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: let me check this .

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: Actually, I have to show the user highlighted parts as well with the whole given string

Comment: And the class="mark" this classname will be diff each time

Comment: Its not like that I have to show a full document with the highlighted text and not the string which is only highlighted

Comment: Hey, Your solution is working, But still the same issue, Now what happening is that duplicate text is getting added. Because some part is in the previous and for next that part is  in another , So, its creating issues.

Comment: That is the only issue now.

Comment: Hey can you please check this ?

Comment: Okay.. Thanks a lot  for this

Comment: Hey, I am really sorry for asking you this. Did you get anything ?

Comment: I wont have time today, sorry

Comment: SO is not about doing your job/homework on your behalf. I have given you a good headstart, why don't you give it a try and post a new question if you get stuck

Comment: Hey, sorry for asking you that. I actually tried all the things with your solution, like removing the duplicates from that array but it is  now removing the extra fields that were highlighted but it is now again the same problem , I want to have that overlapping text as well.

Comment: Hey, I tried lots of the things but still, I am not able to resolve this issue.Coould you please look what can I do for that duplicate text.